# Generating classes in Visual Studio. Advice needed on approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Not sure the best way to achieve this and I would like your input.

I would like to generate a View -  a ViewModel and another couple of classes.
I don't want to generate a project but just some classes.
Implementing the IWizard can you generate more than one class at one time?

Ideally I would like the user to click on a template in visual studio ,input some names etc... and generate this 4-5 classes for them.

What is the best to achieve this? Any links or suggestions on approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a T4 template. The engine's built right in to Visual Studio 2010, and there's a good free editor you can get through the Extension Manager (Tools > Extension Manager > Online > Search for "tangible T4").

As for how to code the templates, here's a good blog post on it which will get you started:

http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/

There's some info in MSDN too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Comment: Hi,I thought of T4 in the past but just wondering about the learning curve.I have not got much time.Do you know some good examples apart from olegsynch?thanks

Comment: The learning curve isn't too steep. If you have the syntax highlighting that the tangible tools gets you, it's not too bad.

Comment: Looking for an example where you can pass parameters to a t4 template.

Comment: If you grab the T4MVC template (http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC), there's an example of settings being stored in another file.